# Windows hangs on running react-native run-android

Tags: performance, android-studio, react-native

I'm just starting out react Native and I've set everything up according to the doc, but whenever I run the run `react-native run-android` command the windows gets stuck and eventually shuts down.

I get the following error sometimes;

1. Memory too low
2. `Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.2-5326820`
3. The js dependency graph does not resolve as well

I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: Need to see the whole error and your configuration. This isn't sufficient information to go on.

Comment: I often can't figure the error out yet, it often shuts down after hanging for a while

Comment: What happens when you run `react-native start`?

Comment: It still gets stuck, the graph never resolves and eventually shutdown the pc

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak or infinite loop somewhere that's sucking all resources and sending the machine into a panic. Will need to see more/all of the code and configuration that you've setup to diagnose further.